# Starting subtask 'configure-webpack' not loading/working

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, gulp

Whenever I run `gulp serve` in Windows PowerShell, I keep getting stuck on the same part. 'Configure-webpack' stays stagnant until it times out 15 minutes later and cancels the request. Any idea why this is happening? The code from running 'gulp serve' in PowerShell is below.

```
[12:11:23] Finished subtask 'sass' after 666 ms
[12:11:23] Starting subtask 'lint'...
[12:11:23] [lint] eslint version: 8.7.0
[12:11:23] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[12:11:23] [tsc] typescript version: 4.5.5
  Request: '/temp/manifests.js'
[12:11:28] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 5.36 s
[12:11:30] Finished subtask 'lint' after 7.4 s
[12:11:32] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 9.18 s
[12:11:32] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[12:11:32] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 182 μs
[12:11:32] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
```

I've tried looking for help everywhere online and I can't find someone that has solved the same problem.